# Latest version of nuget package still not up to date

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019

We are using our own nuget server on the local network. 
I've got a dotnet standard 2.0 library which I'm packaging via nuget. Currently it's at 1.0.5.4 (both File version and Assembly version).

However when I install it in another solution it's missing a property that I added in the latest version increment. When I F12 on a class of that nuget it reads at the top:

```
    #region Assembly lib-mycode-async, Version=1.0.5.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
    // C:\Users\{Username}\.nuget\packages\lib.mycode\1.0.5.4\lib\netstandard2.0\lib-mycode-async.dll
    #endregion
```

In the nuget Manager GUI of Visual Studio it says 1.0.5.4 everywhere. I uninstalled the nuget from all projects of the solution,

- uninstalled any other package that used that particular nuget
- did `Update-Package -reinstall` to reinstall all nuget packages in the solution
- closed and reopened Visual Studio (2019 but also remember having had this with 2017)
- rebuild the nuget packages
- cleaned the nuget package cache in Options > Nuget Package Manager > General > Clear All NuGet Cache(s)

Why does it appear to be up to date everywhere and still I cannot use the latest code changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While writing the question I followed the path in the meta data. 
The .dll file the path points to indeed had the version 1.0.5.1 so I deleted the entire folder `lib.mycode` in `C:\Users\{Username}\.nuget\packages`.

I rebuild my solution, closed VS 2019 and reopened the solution.

Now the folder was back but with the right version. The code was finally there which I added in the latest version of my nuget package.

I really thought that this would have been taken care of by the last point I tried out in the question above!

Comment: Hi friend, we are so glad to hear that your issue is solved and thank you for your sharing. Please mark your reply as answer when you have free time, that will help other community members to easier search this helpful information, thanks in advance.

Comment: will do once SO allows it... in about 3 hours