# Where does the "Go To Definition" version number come from?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2019, go-to-definition

In Visual Studio 2019, if you right click on a symbol, you can select "Go To Definition".  If the symbol is not defined in your code, it will attempt to generate the code from the dll.

When it generates this file, it puts a `#region` comment at the top of it.  This is an example of what my region comment looks like:

```
#region Assembly Logging.Client, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// C:\Users\myUserId\.nuget\packages\logging.client\7.0.0.43\lib\netstandard2.0\Logging.Client.dll
#endregion
```

The key part is that it says `Version=6.0.1.0`.  I opened up the NuGet file, and, on the properties of Logging.Client.dll, the version says 7.0.0.43:

[image: Propertes for the Logging.Client.dll]

So, my question is: **Where does the version number shown on the line of the `#region` comment get pulled from?**

NOTE: I looked at this similar question, but the steps of deleting the existing packages, restarting Visual Studio and rebuilding did not resolve my issue: [Latest version of nuget package still not up to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55575713/latest-version-of-nuget-package-still-not-up-to-date)

Comment: Was `Logging.Client` nuget packag created by yourself? I cannot find it on `nuget.org`. Besides, did your main project a `net framework` or a `net core` project?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT - It was created by myself and is hosted on an internal NuGet server.  It is a `netstandard2.0` project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where does the “Go To Definition” version number come from?

It is from **AssemblyVerion** attribute on VS and it is set in your nuget project by the nuget author.

Please see the below interpretation.

===================================================================

I assume that `logging.client` nuget package is your own nuget package.(created by yourself)

**This is a normal behavior of the nuget and assembly mechanism. It is not an issue and it is just defined that way by the author of the package.**

These make sense and are defined by the author when the nuget package is created and **can be modified by the author.**  It's just that they have different functions from each other to deal with the mechanism of nuget.

The `Version=6.0.1.0` is the assembly version of the dll which used by framework. It is a built-in version number which is used during build or used at runtime. It can only be accessed by vs internally. **To be precise**, this is its real version number.

And `File Version 7.0.0.43` is the version of the dll, which is used for external display and can be accessed externally.

And `Product Version 7.0.0.43` means the nuget package version which also can access outside VS.

**So, they all are defined by the author as he want.**

See [this official document about the function of these attributes: Use AssemblyVersion and AssemblyFileVersion attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/visualstudio/general/assembly-version-assembly-file-version).

They all have professional terms in VS:

**AssemblyVersion** means `6.0.1.0`, AssemblyFileVersion means `File Version 7.0.0.43`  and **NugetVersion** means `Product Version 7.0.0.43`. And they can be also access outside VS.

====================================================

**In my side**, I created a `net standarad` class library project called `ClassLibrary1`.

**Right-click** on your `net standard` class library project, right-click on your project **Properties**-->**Package**

[image: The Package properties dialog includes the package version, assembly version, and assembly file version.]

**1）**

[image]

The **Assembly version** is used under `Logging.Client, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`.

When you install that package on the main project, on the main project, click on the dll on the **References** and you will see the internal version `6.0.1.0` under the **Properties** Window.

[image]

And when you install this package on a `net framework` project with `packages.config`, it will shows on the `csproj` file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ClassLibrary1, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <HintPath>..\packages\ClassLibrary1.7.0.0.43\lib\netstandard2.0\ClassLibrary1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

**The version is used by the internal framework and at build or runtime and only be seen in VS.**

**2)**

[image]

The **Assembly File version** is the file name, it shows on the dll's properties and shows outside VS as **File Version** which you described on the case.

**3)**

[image]

The **Package Version** is the version of the nuget package rather than the assembly dll version. They're different concepts.

**In your side**, it shows like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ClassLibrary1, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
        <HintPath>..\packages\ClassLibrary1.7.0.0.43\lib\netstandard2.0\ClassLibrary1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

And in the dll's properties, it shows as **Product Version**.

[image]

**Overall**，it is not an issue and each of them has a meaningful and specific function. If you want to change this, you should change your nuget project's **Properties**-->**Package** as I said above, modify them as the same. Then, repack its as nuget package.